# Is there any API for checking flight status with confirmation code as input in android?

Tags: android

I am creating an android app and I need to verify the confirmation code entered by the user is a valid or not by parsing the code with the particular website. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are apis for [flight status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895064/web-based-flight-status-api), yes. Thought unfortunately, they seem to be all apis you have to pay for.

For the confirmation number, according to United it can be found on your boarding pass.

So if you're just trying to do some quick validation, perhaps even do some offline validation, it may be possible to do so if you study the minimum standards used for boarding passes, which can be found [here](http://shaun.net/2011/05/whats-contained-in-a-boarding-pass-barcode/) and which includes a reference to the "booking number". Please take a look at the comments on that blog post as well, not just the post itself.

The "booking number" in this case is probably the confirmation code, I would think.